# Can't import win32api while I can see it in my files

Tags: python-3.x, email, winapi, pywin32, win32com

I'm relatively new to coding in general, and I'm trying to automate the process of sending a specific email I do regularly at work using Python. I found some code that seemed to accomplish my goal, but I can't get it to import the win32api module correctly.

I'm using the PyCharm IDE, and I have installed win32 using pip successfully. When I check under site-packages\win32 I can clearly see the win32api.pyd file there, together with a bunch of other files. But when I try to import it, it's not found.
When I write:

```py
from win32 import
```

the only option I get is _win32sysloader

The site-packages folder is in my PYTHONPATH, I have been able to import the openpyxl module in the same way, but this one is not as cooperative.

Here's the code I'm using:

```py
import win32com.client
import win32

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch(r"path\to\outlook.exe")
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = "my@mail.com
mail.Subject = "Test"
mail.Body = "Mail"
mail.Send
```

In the end, what I'm trying to accomplish is to automatically send an email to a specific address with a certain text string. But when I run this code I get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
If you have any other recommendations regarding how to accomplish this I'd be happy to hear them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Win32 module is not required.

And you didn't use `win32com.client.Dispatch` correctly.

> Automation objects are COM objects that expose methods and properties
>   using the IDispatch interface. So how do we use these objects from
>   Python? The win32com.client package contains a number of modules to
>   provide access to automation objects.
>
> To use an IDispatch-based COM object, use the method
>   win32com.client.Dispatch(). This method takes as its first parameter
>   the ProgID or CLSID of the object you wish to create. If you read the
>   documentation for Microsoft Outlook, you'll find the ProgID for
>   Outlook is outlook.application, so to create an object that interfaces
>   to Outlook.

You should modify it like this.

After testing, it is effective.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = "my@mail.com"
mail.Subject = "Test"
mail.Body = "Mail"

mail.Send()
```

And this will use your local outlook account.

Comment: Hello, thanks for clarifying the outlook.application part!
However, I straight up copy-pasted your code, and I still get the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'" error... Am I missing something really obvious...? :/

Comment: @Niklas You need to install Win32 module, using `pip install pypiwin32`

Comment: Yea that's the first thing I did. pypiwin32 successfully installed using pip, as I stated in my first post. 
In Lib\site-packages I can see the win32, win32com, win32comext and win32ctypes folders. 
I also have the Lib\site-packages folder as a part of my PYTHONPATH environmental variable. 
If I check under External Libraries\Lib\site-packages inside the PyCharm IDE I can see all of those folders there as well, so the IDE can see the files are there, just not load them in the actual code it seems.

Comment: @Niklas This seems to be the problem of PyCharm. [Here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000058690-Module-not-found-in-PyCharm-but-externally-in-Python) is a detailed record. I'm using Python 3.7, not PyCharm.

Comment: Aha great! The solution provided by Uvaisbsc in the post you linked help me get past the error! Thanks a lot!
Now I just need to figure out why the email is not showing up in my inbox... The code executes without error, exit code 0. But no email to be seen anywhere.

Comment: And I found why I did not receive the email. The () at the end of mail.Send got lost during copy-pasting.... Once I added that, it works like a charm.
Thanks for the help!